# what will be the sql query for checking same pairs of column values in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table emp(id , name, salary) and having no primary key (i know that is a bad idea but my work is on inconsistent table)
I want a query to retrieve tuples which have same pairs of values (id, name)
i tried using self join but not getting exact statement.
Here same pair is considering but i am working for more than 2 attributes for comparison. plz help
Example

```
     id     name   salary
     1      a       100
     1      b       100
     2      a       200

     1      a       300
     2      c       200
```

So i want to find tuple with same value of id and name. here it is(1,a)

Answer (score 7):

You can find them by grouping and only choosing those record where the count is greater than 1:

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID, Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use the exists clause for this, it's fast.

just add more AND's if you need more comparisons on the columns.

```
   select * from  table_name a
   where exists ( select 1 from table_name b where a.salary != b.salary 
   and a.id = b.id
   and a.name = b.name)
```

But this will not give a result if the record is exactly the same, in you case if both records also have the same salary.

In Oracle I would be using rowid identifier for that but that doesn't exist in my

Answer (score 0):

You can use count, group by and having.

```
select
  id,
  name,
  count(*)
from
  mytable
group by
  id,name
having
  count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion first:
If you are not applying primary key to the table (due to your requirement), at atleast set index on (id, name) so that results generate faster.

Query to fetch distinct (id, name) pairs:
SELECT distinct id, name FROM emp;

If requirement is to also fetch total salary amount:
SELECT id, name, sum(salary) as salary FROM emp group by id, name;

Hope it helps.